# How to correct the subscript indicies mut be integers error in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot the 3 roots of my function as they vary with my K vector.  I know the the index of my r matrix must be an integer but even when I use the small k vector it still gives the same error.  How should I fix this issue?

```
%problem 3d
clear,clc
K=0:.01:2;
%K=10
k=0:1:2000;
r(K,:)=roots([1,1.76,5.31,(4.55+4.6.*K)])
%r1=roots([1,.76+(4.6*K),(4.55+(9.2*K))])

figure(1)
plot(real(r(1,:)),imag(r(1,:)),'*')
```

Comment: Matlab indexing starts from 1, not 0.

Comment: Correct it by actually reading the error. It doesn't say integers, it says **positive integers** i.e. zero excluded.

Answer (score 1):

Several comments:

- Indices in MATLAB must be positive integers (eg. `1, 2, 3, ...`).
- Your K vector has non-integer numbers beginning at zero: `0, .01, .02, .03, ...` hence they cannot be array indices.
- Why not do: `r = roots([1,1.76,5.31,(4.55+4.6.*K)])`?

If this is confusing, I would also go through some [Matlab array indexing tutorials](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/array-indexing.html).

Comment: Because I need all the values of r based off of K so i can plot them.  Even if my K is defined as K=0:1:2000 I still get the same error

Comment: starting at 0 and not 1 was my original problem.  Now the error is Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Comment: @Wes What's on the left and right hand side of your assignment operator (i.e. `=`) have different dimensions.

Comment: Ok I was able to fix the problem thank you very much for the help!